# How to find out if the Quartz Job is paused

Tags: java, quartz

In my Spring Boot application I used Quartz `org.quartz.Scheduler` to schedule a job:

```
final JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob().ofType(ReportSendingJob.class)
    .storeDurably()
    .withIdentity("myJob")
    .build();

final CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(job)
    .withIdentity(scheduleName)
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(schedule.getCronExpression()).withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
                .build();

scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

then I paused it:

```
scheduler.pauseJob(new JobKey("myJob"));
```

How can I get the status of this job to see if it is paused or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation of `pauseJob` method says

> Pause the JobDetail with the given key - by pausing all of its current Triggers.

So you could check if job is paused by checking if all triggers are paused:

```
List<Trigger> triggers = scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(JobKey.jobKey("myJob"))

boolean paused = triggers
    .stream()
    .allMatch( trigger -> 
        scheduler.getTriggerState(trigger.key) == PAUSED 
    )
```